# Xcode git repository offline

Tags: xcode, git

On my iMac I am getting the error message 'Repository Offline' when trying to push or pull to and from my git repository through Xcode!

in the sidebar under Source Control it has the name of my repository and a green light!

I also have access to the same repository on my macbook through Xcode, I can push and pull fine!

There appears to be something wrong with Xcode on my iMac but I have no idea how to fix it.. I created a brand new repository and had the same problem, but again I could access it fine from my Macbook

Any advice?

Regards
Byron

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing the remote origin and adding it through terminal

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Removing origin and adding through terminal

Answer (score 1):

Just Restart Xcode or System then it will worked